# High charts Donut Chart not rendering

Tags: highcharts

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kVGTh/

My chart seems identical to the demo one found on HighCharts site.  I have been at this for an hour and have gone line by line.  I made sure I have the correct js libraries, the div matches, the jQuery version is the same.  I am at a loss, any help is appreciated. The only part I am not entirely sure about is this:

```
            for (var j = 0; j < data[i].drilldown.data.length; j++) {
            var brightness = 0.2 - (j / data[i].drilldown.data.length) / 5 ;
            versionsData.push({
                name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
                y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
                color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get()
```

I am at a loss, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing single quotes:

name: Animal,

Should be:

name: 'Animal',

Comment: Names needs to be string, in your example it is vatiable which doens't exist.